# Dataset with no members

Tags: dataset

I am trying to plan a framework for relational algebra using the Dataset capability of Mathematica 10.

In the work of Date and Darwen, there are [two concepts](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TableDee) known as TABLE_DEE and TABLE_DUM.  TABLE_DEE is a relation with a (column) header but no rows, whereas TABLE_DUM is simply:

Dataset[{}]

How might I create a TABLE_DEE with Dataset--a table with headers, but no data? I feel this would allow a framework for performing orthodox relational database operations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use the undocumented (and subject-to-change) syntax for specifying a type or schema:

```
Needs["TypeSystem`"];
Dataset[
  {}, 
  Vector @ Struct[
    "field1" -> Atom[Integer], 
    "field2" -> Atom[String]
  ]
]
```

Replace the contents of the inner `Struct` as you see fit (you can always use TypeSystem`DeduceType on a chunk of data obeying your desired schema to see more examples of these type expressions).

Comment: Your code produces an error message `Dataset::data: Data does not conform to type <...>` and does not produce "a table with headers, but no data" (citing the question).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I'm sorry, you have to write `Needs["TypeSystem`"]` before evaluating my code. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Thanks for your reply.  I gathered that you are the author of this code.  I'm really happy about this functionality, especially the ability to have data sets inside of data sets (relations inside of relations).

Answer (score 2):

We can create a table with a header and no rows like this:

```
Dataset[{<|"header" -> 1|>}] @ Select[False &]
```

[image: dataset screenshot]

This uses only documented functionality.